# Is bootstrap included in Laravel 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I have "bootstrap" subfolder in my laravel app, is that means bootstrap is included in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `bootstrap` doesn't just refer to Twitter Bootstrap. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping):

> In general parlance, bootstrapping usually refers to the starting of a
>   self-sustaining process that is supposed to proceed without external
>   input. In computer technology the term (usually shortened to booting)
>   usually refers to the process of loading the basic software into the
>   memory of a computer after power-on or general reset, especially the
>   operating system which will then take care of loading other software
>   as needed.

**Note** that also on Stack Overflow, the [bootstrap] tag does [NOT refer to Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap). That's what the [twitter-bootstrap] tag is for.

### So what is it actually?

The few files in the `bootstrap` directory will, bootstrap, start, initialize the application.

- **autoload.php** Autoload classes from `vendor/autoload` and `compiled.php` if possible
- (**compiled.php**) Precompiled framework classes
- **paths.php** Defines important paths relative to the `bootstrap` dir
- **start.php** "Starts" the application. Environment detection, loading paths and creating an instance of the container `Application`

Answer (score 2):

You can have twitter bootstrap on your project folder, but if you want to use all the styles and libraries of bootstrap you need to include in your master.blade the **.js** and **.css** bootstrap files

Example:

```
{{ HTML::script('http://public/assets/js/bootstrap.3.0.0.min.css') }} // This include all the css files of bootstrap.

{{ HTML::script('http://public/assets/js/bootstrap.3.0.0.min.js') }} // This include rapall the functionalities of bootstrap
```

Of course you need to add your own bootstrap files and path.

Once you have include the .js and .css you can use all the staff of bootstrap like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
```

The class **btn btn-info** it's a style of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. What you had saw bootstrap folder in your laravel app include

- `autoload.php`
- `paths.php` and
- `start.php`

Read more about laravel [Request Lifecycle on laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle), to know how Laravel work.